# Filtering on json import in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am learning d3js and stuck on some simple steps... I am importing json data and need to filter only data of year 2010.
This is my import part:

```
d3.json("data/data.json").then(data => {
    data.forEach(d => {
        d.income = +d.income
        d.life_exp = +d.life_exp
        d.year = +d.year
    })
})
```

Where and how I need to add filtering part?

Comment: Let me understand: You want to load CSV and then keep just 2010 rows and filter out all the others?

Comment: Yes, right! And I want to do it while importing data or creating new dataset, but not adding filter in ```svg.selectAll``` part.

Answer (score 1):

Just insert **filter** before **forEach**:

```
d3.json("data/data.json")
  .then(data => data
    .filter(d => d.year === 2010)
    .forEach(d => {
        ...
    })
)
```